# Aptana Studio 3 - code coloring like in Dreamweaver

Tags: aptana

I'm trying to use Aptana Studio 3 instead of phpEd. But I'd like to have the code coloring like in Dreamweaver. I made these changes in phpEd, but I can't find where to change it in Aptana.

Also, I installed the jquery bundle, but I can't to get it working...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Preferences:Aptana:Themes. Figuring out what keyword corresponds to what display object can be a bit tricky, but it is all there.

Comment: Thanks. But I can't find anything for php! What is the rule to add new elements to Themes elements list? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I'm comparing Aptana 2 and Aptana 3. In Aptana 2 there are a place to customize php colors (Preferances-PHP). In Aptana 3 there are no this item! How can I add it to Aptana 3 ?

Answer (score 3):

There's actually a ticket already filed to add a theme that matches Dreamweaver: https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272/tickets/1508-create-dreamweaver-color-theme

I'm looking at it now, but I'm running into some internal bugs (namely https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272-studio/tickets/2357-scope-selectors-with-portion-prefix-match-arent-matching-properly) that I need to fix before I can finish. In any case it should be in Studio 3.0.2 and hopefully I'll fix it today and it'll be in tomorrow's nightly (here's how to get nightly builds: http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Changing+the+Update+Type).

As for editing themes yourself, you can see the current scope at the cursor by doing Commands > Bundle Development > Show Scope. Then use scope selectors that match that sort of scope (we adopt Textmate's scoping/theming rules: http://manual.macromates.com/en/scope_selectors)

Answer (score 2):

Could you finally get your theme? 
If you want to create your own theme then first go to: *Window->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Themes*

- To create a new theme just click on the "**+**" sign next to the themes
  list.
- To add elements to your new theme right click the text in your
  editor and click *Commands->Bundle Development->Show scope*.
- Copy the last section you see to the right of the hint window that
  appears.
- In the themes elements list click the "**+**" located at the bottom of
  the dialog box (next to "Scope selector")
- Give a friendly name to your new element.
- Assign foreground/background colors to your new element.
- Paste the element's scope in the "Scope selector" input box (make
  sure your new element is selected, if not, click on it).

I created a theme for PHP, CSS, HTML, JS and XML editors, similar to the old aptana 2 colors. If you want to get it you can write me to jgarcias.cr at gmail dot com.

Cheers.